# Is it a bad sign not to call the parent's method from the overridden method?

Tags: php, inheritance, phpstorm

```
class A
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'First class';
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Second class';
    }
}
```

Phpstorm then warns me and highlights `B::getName()` that I missed to call its parent: `parent::getName();` I intentionally don't call it. But this leads me the conclusion that its a sign of something bad.

Comment: It shouldn't warn you unless the method is not constructor. I tried the same thing in PhpStrom 2017.3.2 There is no warning.

Comment: You can elect to call the parent method in your overridden method, but _you don't have to_.  I'm not sure whether Phpstorm is giving you a spurious warning but it's definitely safe to ignore if your intention is to override the behaviour

Comment: Please update the question with the example relevant to your question - the short answer is yes, it's a common code error - but there are plenty of times you don't want to do that.

Comment: How is that a common code error?

Comment: @DarkBee I dont know! But since PhpStorm is saying that, and is the wideliest used IDE, it must be be somewhat true

Comment: JohnSmith my comment was aimed to @AD7six

Comment: @DarkBee I can provide an answer when the question is updated, I'm not going to answer the question in a comment :).

Comment: @AD7six the example is already just fine, if I want to re-name something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inspection is located in a *Probable bugs* inspections group - it means that's not an error and not something bad that IDE is sure about. The inspection itself is disabled by default, you might've enabled it on your own. The idea of this inspection is described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4414):

> Generally, when you override a method (especially a constructor), you want to call the parent method in it. An info inspection for lack of parent:: call could be handy

Comment: ok. All in all, I thought it was a "code smell"